# In textfield i have to check Unicode SWIFT CODE is "\u{ef}"

Tags: swift, unicode, textview

In Swift i am found one Unicode so I Have use one check if textfield have this unicode "\u{ef}" condition is false

Here is my code 
But is not Working

```
let getMessage =  self.txtChat_View?.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

        if(String(describing: getMessage?.characters) == "\u{ef}")
        {
           print("gdfsds")
        }
        print(String(describing: getMessage?.characters)) //ANS Blank
        print("-------------------------------") 
        print("---------->",getMessage ?? String()) //ANS Blank
        print(getMessage?.characters.count) //ANS count is 1 



        if(getMessage ?? String() == "\u{ef}")
        {
         print("This is unicode")
        }
        if(getMessage == "")
        {
            print("This is null")
        }
        if(getMessage == nil)
        {
            print("@@@@NIL@@@@@")
        }
```

Comment: That could would be greatly simplieifed if you just unwrapped `getMessage`.

Comment: How can i unwrapped , Please share with me code or any link .